# INSERT ... SELECT to error on non matching query criteria

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a schema like so:

```
CREATE TABLE user (
    id uuid NOT NULL,
    device_id uuid PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL 
); 
ALTER TABLE user ADD CONSTRAINT unique_ids UNIQUE (id);


CREATE TABLE hit (
    initiator uuid NOT NULL,
    target uuid NOT NULL 
);


ALTER TABLE hit ADD CONSTRAINT initiator_fk FOREIGN KEY (initiator) REFERENCES user (id);          
ALTER TABLE hit ADD CONSTRAINT target_fk FOREIGN KEY (target) REFERENCES user (id); 
ALTER TABLE hit ADD CONSTRAINT unique_hits UNIQUE (initiator, target);
```

and an `INSERT` statement which I want to insert that `hit`.

```
INSERT INTO hit (initiator, target) 
SELECT user.id, $1 
FROM user 
WHERE user.device_id = $2;
```

So when one `user` wants to `hit` another I have the `initiator.device_id` and the `target.id` on hand. This query works fine in two of my three cases (both valid values, id invalid, device_id invalid) but the latter; when the `initiator.device_id` is an invalid (non-existing) value. The result is a non-erroring statement which leaves me to evaluate the rows affected (0) - I would prefer if this would come back as a constraint violation, am I able to do this?

I am using PostgreSQL 9.3.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
INSERT INTO hit (initiator, target) 
SELECT coalesce(user.id,0), coalesce($1,0)
FROM dual left join user on 1=1
WHERE user.device_id = $2;
```

(Instead of the dual table you should use any table with exactly one row.)